# Test your code locally without using localhost

Tags: security, https, localhost

This might sound like an odd question but I travel a lot and therefore sometimes I need to connect to public networks.

Now, testing my code changes in `localhost` isn't secure and I am unable to set up a `htttps` connection or `ssl certificates` at the moment. The best thing I can do is to use a `VPN`extension. Does anyone have an alternative to this? For example some kind of plugin in `VS code` that allows you to test locally without using an internet connection?

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you!

Comment: Sir, I believe you need a firewall. A simple rule to disallow connections from other places than localhost would be enough.

Comment: thanks @MarekPuchalski I got that so maybe I am ok :D

Comment: This can be tested! In a local network use some other computer to access the port. The request should be rejected.